# How do I create my own pytest fixture?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I would like to create my own pytest fixture where I can insert what I want it to do in the setup and teardown phase.

I am looking for something like this (in this example, i create a file that's needed for the test):

```
@pytest.fixture
def file(path, content):
    def setup():
        # check that file does NOT exist
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            raise Exception('file already exists')

        # put contents in the file
        with open(path, 'w') as file:
            file.write(content)
    def teardown():
        os.remove(path)
```

and I would like to be able to use it like this:

```
def test_my_function(file):
    file('/Users/Me/myapplication/info.txt', 'ham, eggs, orange juice')
    assert my_function('info') == ['ham', 'eggs', 'orange juice']
```

I am aware there is already a `tempdir` fixture in pytest that has similar functionality.  Unfortunately, that fixture only creates files somewhere within the `/tmp` directory, and I need files in my application.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I'm getting pretty close.  The following almost works, but it doesn't set the PATH variable global to the fixture like I expected.  I'm wondering if I can create a class instead of a function for my fixture.

```
@pytest.fixture
def file(request):
    PATH = None
    def setup(path, content):
        PATH = path

        # check that file does NOT exist
        if os.path.isfile(PATH):
            raise Exception('file already exists')

        # put contents in the file
        with open(PATH, 'w+') as file:
            file.write(content)
    def teardown():
        os.remove(PATH)
    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return setup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit crazy, but here is a solution:

```
@pytest.fixture
def file(request):
    class File:
        def __call__(self, path, content):
            self.path = path

            # check that file does NOT exist
            if os.path.isfile(self.path):
                raise Exception('file already exists')

            # put contents in the file
            with open(self.path, 'w+') as file:
                file.write(content)
        def teardown(self):
            os.remove(self.path)
    obj = File()
    request.addfinalizer(obj.teardown)
    return obj
```

Comment: I can't share my specific solution, but it is along the lines of this general idea, and seems to work nicely.  My version has a stack that keeps track of all files created, and then deletes them all at the end.  I also decided to use the Send2Trash module so that deletes files would go to my computer's trash instead of being permanently removed immediately.  This can be helpful for troubleshooting purposes if the code fails, etc.